# Existing publication in Google Scholar profile vanished

Tags: publications, google-scholar

During January 2017 I noticed that one of my publications from 2000 that had a significant number of citations had disappeared from my Google Scholar publication list. I re-entered the missing publication manually, however, the citations have not reappeared. Rather another author’s paper appeared in my publication list with several hundred citations. I noticed the same problem in a colleague’s Google Scholar publication list.

Any suggestions to resolve the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing much to do except for things which you already did and can try again:

1. Add/remove the publication manually
2. Submit a request for correction
3. Contact Google Scholar directly for help about this specific problem (https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general)

The Scholar system is highly automated, and their automatic methods for parsing/counting of citations can change abruptly and cause general fluctuations in the level of citation. I have noticed it is quite common to see my citation count suddenly increase or decrease by as much as 100 citations (and in one case it changed by more than 500).

Alternatively you can use other citation count resources such as Web of Science or Scopus.

Comment: Speaking of abrupt changes in Google Scholar's citation count, there was [this experiment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.0638)...

Answer (score 5):

Some time ago Google Scholar started to cite old APS and some other journals differently. For example, my paper previously cited as

Possible metal-insulator transition at B= 0 in two dimensions
SV Kravchenko, GV Kravchenko, JE Furneaux, VM Pudalov, M D’Iorio
Physical Review B 50 (11), 8039 (1994)

is now cited as

SV Kravchenko, GV Kravchenko, JE Furneaux, VM Pudalov, and M. D’Iorio, Phys. Rev. B 50, 8039 (1994).
SV Kravchenko
Phys. Rev. B 50, 8039

This will not make much difference if you are the first author. But if you are not, all citations to this paper will disappear in your profile.

Solution: if you are not the first author of a certain paper, click on "+" on your Google Scholar page and then on "Add articles". Search for the first author's papers in which you are a co-author, select them and click on update (a tick in the upper right corner). The paper and the corresponding citations will be added to your profile.